# Persistency of botulinum toxin in environment

Tags: toxicology, environment, bacterial-toxins

There is information about decontamination times [here on pages 6 and 7](http://www.cdc.gov/biosafety/publications/bmbl5/BMBL5_appendixI.pdf). My specific question is how persistent botulinum toxin is in a natural environment, or alternatively, what is the half life of this toxin?

Comment: I think you shoudld narrow down the scope by asking about specific biotoxins or groups of toxins. From what I know, persistency can vary dramatically between groups and types of toxins.